# python - number of days in between

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am pretty new to Python. I am trying to subtract datetime from today's day, but I am getting the following an error when I run the following code:

`temp['datetime'] - date.today()`

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and
> 'datetime.date

Sample data and data types are provided below:

```
datetime     datetime64[ns]
machineID             int64
comp                 object
dtype: object
```

Table:

```
        datetime        |machineID  | errorID
0   03/01/2015 07:00:00 |    1      |  error1
1   03/01/2015 20:00:00 |    1      |  error3
2   04/01/2015 06:00:00 |    1      |  error5
3   10/01/2015 15:00:00 |    1      |  error4
4   22/01/2015 10:00:00 |    1      |  error4
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can answer me on how to solve this problem.

Comment: What version of pandas and python are you using? Works fine for me.

Comment: Please show a *complete* example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is interesting. I am on pandas `1.0.1` and I has the same error as yours.

To overcome this error, you need to wrap `date.today()` in `Timestamp`

```
from datetime import date

df.datetime - pd.Timestamp(date.today())

Out[91]:
0   -2000 days +07:00:00
1   -2000 days +20:00:00
2   -1969 days +06:00:00
3   -1786 days +15:00:00
4   -2038 days +10:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: This worked! thanks!

Answer (score -1):

i think you should use
`pd.to_datetime('today')` instead of `date.today()`